# How to display custom WP menus?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, menus

My task is to create local menu which will be displayed if specific page is open (checking page). For now I would like to display my custom menu. I am creating custom menu from Appeerance-Menus. After theat in functions.php I am doing the following:

```
function register_my_menus() {
 register_nav_menus(
  array(
  'explore_menu' => __( 'Explore Menu' ),
      )
    );
  }

 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

AFter that I mark the check box Explore menu in the dashboard, such that my menu is marked as Explore menu. In my page.php I am adding this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">  
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'explore_menu'
    ) );
 ?>
```

I expect to see the menu I created, but I dont see it. WHat could be the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago and solved it by adding my custom menu in my custom theme `header.php` (inside  tag) instead of `page.php`.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) );
```

[Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/) you can find a brief explanation about how to create and insert your custom menu

Hope you can solve it!